# Gerando tabela dinamica com Jquery

Tags: jquery

Estou com o seguinte problema,estou fazendo um cambo de busca ,para pesquisar pelo nome do cliente ,até aqui tudo bem ,consegui trazer os cliente porem ele estão em um array ,meu problema é como eu faço para dividir cada cliente em linha separada

Quero assim :

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Porem esta vindo assim :

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Ja tentei usar o $.each encadeado ,mas ele acaba duplicando os registro ,se for pega apenas um dos registro da certo ,porem o nome tem que esta na mesma linha que seu ID e IDADE

```
success: function (data, status) {
                var valoresID;
                var arrID = [];
                var arrNome = [];
                var arrIdade = [];

                for (var i = 0; i < data.d.length; i++) {

                    var item = JSON.stringify(data.d[i]["ID"]);

                    arrID.push(data.d[i]["ID"]);
                    arrNome.push(data.d[i]["Nome"]);
                    arrIdade.push(data.d[i]["Idade"]);


                }
                $('.child').remove()
                $('.valorTr').after('<tr class="child"><td>'+JSON.stringify(arrID)+'</td><td>'+arrNome+'</td><td>'+arrIdade+'</td></tr>');

            }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Isso acontece por que você está usando o `JSON.stringify` que transforma seu array numa string.

Para resolver seu problema você pode fazer o seguinte:

```
for (i =0; i < arrID.length; i++){
 $('.valorTr').after('<tr class="child"><td>'+arrID[i]+'</td><td>'+arrNome[i]+'</td><td>'+arrIdade[i]+'</td></tr>');
}
```

Uma solução melhor seria você trabalhar somente com um array contendo o objeto que você recupera:

```js
dadosTabela = []

// código omitido (loop dos dados)
dadosTabela.push(dados = {
  "Id": 1,
  "Nome": "Laerte",
  "Idade": 23
})
dadosTabela.push(dados = {
  "Id": 2,
  "Nome": "João",
  "Idade": 18
})

dadosTabela.forEach(x => console.log(x['Id'] + '\t' + x['Nome'] + '\t' + x['Idade']))
```

Comment: Deu certo,obrigado vou ver a sua segunda forma.